# Drag parent div but only accept drop if child element is in right place

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a draggable parent element (ice cream wrapper), which is bigger than the droppable one (teeth). So I've put another, absolutely positioned child element inside the parent which is fairly small (red square). What I would like to achieve is the following:

- ice cream has to be the one draggable, red marker will not be visible
- red square should also move when dragging the ice cream
- fire "drop" event only when the red square is in inside any of the black marked divs (droppable's), not only part of the ice cream

I already tried some of the "multi drag" libraries but none of them worked as expected. I also tried to use tolerance: pointer option, but since we will be dragging ice cream not the red square, the pointer will usually not be inside the marked droppable.

Image for easier understanding:
[image]

HTML part:

```
<div class="sladoled-wrapper draggable">
    <img src="img/sladoled.png" class="img-sladoled draggable">
    <div class="pointer draggable"></div>
</div>
```

JS part:

```
$( function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
        revert: true
    });
    $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this ).addClass( "dropped" );
        }
    });
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
$( function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
        revert : function(event, ui) {
            // on older version of jQuery use "draggable"
            // $(this).data("draggable")
            // on 2.x versions of jQuery use "ui-draggable"
            // $(this).data("ui-draggable")
            $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
                top : 0,
                left : 0
            };
            // return boolean
            return !event;
            // that evaluate like this:
            // return event !== false ? false : true;
        }
    });
    $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this ).addClass( "dropped" );
        }
    });
} );
```

Comment: Tried it. It doesn't work. The red square starts moving with the parent on second drag and the ice cream becomes undraggable after 2 tries. Thanks anyway.

Comment: can you make fiddle for this, so we can make efforts to sort it out more easily

Comment: I tried, but this is a part of large project which is set up locally at the moment, so it would take a fair amount of time to upload all the things and change their sources + the project needs an apache server to run properly.

Comment: I managed to create some sort of fiddle afterall. Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/uf8w6efu/1/